# How can I take one column from multiple CSV files to create a new dataframe in R?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Essentially I am looking to take the third column from every CSV file in a folder and append it to a data frame as a new column. Ideally I would like the header for each column to be the respective file name. I have about 172 files in the folder, each with a unique filename (i.e. file1.csv, file2.csv, etc) however the title of the third column is the same. Illustrating this on a smaller scale, if I had file 1 and file 2, the output would look like what is shown below.

[image: File1]

[image: File2]

[image: Output]

EDIT: added some clarification.

Comment: I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227, its tricks for using `lapply` is what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

Will your third column always be the same name in both files?

if not you could to the below

```
cbind(file1[,3], file2[,3])
```

`cbind` would combine the data frames by column

Comment: Yes, the third column has the same title in all files. I also should have clarified, and I have updated the original post, but this is for every file in a folder. So I have 172 files in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` to read all the files, extract the 3rd column from it, assign the name of the column same as the file name and bind all such column together in one dataframe.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

do.call(cbind, lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  setNames(data.frame(read.csv(x)[[3]]), tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)))
})) -> result

result
```